# is it possible to turn off screen lock in Mac OSX after 6pm?

Tags: macos, security

I would like to turn off lock screen security when I finish work.

Is it possible to do it on a scheduled basis?

Answer (score 2):

Save for example this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>some.label</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>tell application "System Events" to set require password to wake of security preferences to false</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>18</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`. To apply changes to the plist, unload and load it.

Another option is to run `crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`0 18 * * * osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set require password to wake of security preferences to false'`

If your computer is sleeping at 6 PM, cron doesn't run the command after the computer wakes up but launchd does.

If your computer is locked, the osascript command does not unlock the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) to set rules for changing system behaviors. I've used it for a while now; just set it to detect when you are not at work (using time-based rule, or contextual things like SSIDs and peripherals and etc.). This would also allow you to automatically re-enable the lock when you return to work the next day. I find it really useful for changing screensaver timeout, default printer, enabling/disabling wifi, screen brightness, you name it.

Comment: I am not usually enthusiastic about apps that are not on the App Store. Brilliant app though.